# SparkSession return nothing with an HiveServer2 connection throught JDBC

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, hive, apache-zeppelin

I have an issue about reading data from a remote HiveServer2 using JDBC and SparkSession in Apache Zeppelin.

Here is the code.

```
%spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val prop = new java.util.Properties
prop.setProperty("user","hive")
prop.setProperty("password","hive")
prop.setProperty("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")

val test = spark.read.jdbc("jdbc:hive2://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10000/", "tests.hello_world", prop)

test.select("*").show()
```

When i run this, I've got no errors but no data too, i just retrieve all the column name of table, like this :

```
+--------------+
|hello_world.hw|
+--------------+
+--------------+
```

Instead of this :

```
+--------------+
|hello_world.hw|
+--------------+
+ data_here    +
+--------------+
```

I'am running all of this on :
Scala 2.11.8,
OpenJDK 8,
 Zeppelin 0.7.0,
 Spark 2.1.0 ( [bde/spark](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark/tree/2.1.0-hadoop2.7) ),
 Hive 2.1.1 ( [bde/hive](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hive) )

I run this setup in Docker which each of those have their own container but connected in the same network.

Furthermore it just works when i use use the spark beeline to connect to my remote Hive.

Did i have forgot something ?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

I've found a workaround, which is sharing docker volume or docker data-container between Spark and Hive, more precisily the Hive warehouse folder between them, and with configuring the spark-defaults.conf. Then you can acces hive through SparkSession without JDBC. Here is the step by step to how to do it :

1. Share the Hive warehouse folder between Spark and Hive
2. Configure spark-defaults.conf with like this :

   ```
   spark.serializer     org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer

   spark.driver.memory              Xg

   spark.driver.cores       X

   spark.executor.memory        Xg

   spark.executor.cores         X

   spark.sql.warehouse.dir         file:///your/path/here
   ```

Replace 'X' with your values.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is your table schema have clustering/bucketing ?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you found the solution (or a work-around)?